# How to loop through a list using each item from a list only once to insert at the beginning of another list in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

I'm new to Python and am having trouble completing a task for an assignment. I have defined a function that works well except for the following area: I'm working with a list of 10 strings and I need to insert each string from this list only once to the beginning of a corresponding randomized list of also 10 strings that I made for a file pulled off from the Terminal using `sys.argv`(meaning there are 10 files with one string from my list corresponding to each file). I know I have to use the `.insert(0, new_string)` method to insert the new string from my list of 10 strings.

This is an excerpt of my function showing what I have tried so far to achieve this:

```
randomlist = (list(map(choice, old_list)))
new_list = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6", "string 7", "string8", "string9", "string10"]
for new_string in new_list:
    randomlist.insert(0, new_string)
```

When I run this code, I get an output of a list where every single element from `new_list` is inserted before my `randomlist` elements. This results in a list of 20 elements when it should only be 11.

How the output should look like is something like this (after applying the function to each of the 10 files using `sys.argv`) where `rstring` corresponds to a string from my `randomlist`:

```
["string1", "rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
["string2", "rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
["string3", "rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
["string4", "rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
["string5", "rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
["string6", "rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
["string7", "rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
["string8", "rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
["string9", "rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
["string10", "rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
```

I tried other things too but this is the least messy way I could get the output in. As a recap, I need to use each element from `new_list` only once (in order from left to right) and insert it to the beginning of my `randomlist`. There is a `randomlist` for each file I'm working with and I'm calling them through `sys.argv` I believe it will involve a for loop of some kind and possibly tuples, but I don't know how to make them do what I need them to do. Also, I am not allowed to hard-code anything.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you insert new elements to the same and unique list `randomlist` which is why they all pile up in the end.

You can add an element `item` at the start of (a copy of) `randomlist` (without affecting `randomlist` itself) like this:

```
[item] + randomlist
```

To create all your outputs at once, just nest this in a list comprehension:

```
all_outputs = [[item] + randomlist for item in new_list]
for output in all_outputs:
    print output
```

or if you only need to print them, you can just do this:

```
for item in new_list:
    print [item] + randomlist
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand where I'm adding the line you gave me. I  tried adding that between lines 2 and 3 of the code in my original question and my output was just  the randomlist that was generated without the new_list elements inserted before the randomlist generated. I also tried replacing my line 4 of my question's code with your line and I got the same result.

Comment: It really depends what you want to do with your modified list(s). See edit to just print them out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import random

list1 = ["rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
list2 = ["rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
list3 = ["rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
list4 = ["rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
list5 = ["rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
list6 = ["rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
list7 = ["rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
list8 = ["rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
list9 = ["rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]
list10 = ["rstring1", "rstring2", "rstring3", "rstring4", "rstring5", "rstring6", "rstring7", "rstring8", "rstring9", "rstring10"]

lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7, list8, list9, list10]

new_list = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6", "string7", "string8", "string9", "string10"]
for new_string in new_list:
    randomlist = random.choice(lists) #Selects a random list from pool
    randomlist.insert(0, new_string)
    lists.remove(randomlist) #Removes list from pool once it has been selected

print list1
print list2
print list3
print list4
print list5
print list6
print list7
print list8
print list9
print list10
```

Comment: Do I add this to my existing function from which my code above is a part of? Or is this separate? Sorry I need direction on where to actually insert those lines you gave me. Also, isn't 'l1-item1' the same as ""string1"?

Comment: This is separate. I needed to generate random lists since I did not have `choice` and `old_list` from your code. The main trick was to select the random list from inside the loop and then remove it from the pool so that other items are not added to it.
"l1-item" is present in one of the random lists that you want to added "stringx" elements to.

Comment: I've changed "l1-item" to "rstring1" and likewise for other items.

Comment: I tried the new code you posted and I'm still getting errors. Is there any way to private message you on here? I think it would be easier for you to see what I'm doing wrong if you saw what I tried typing for the input, but I'd rather not post my actual code here publicly.

Comment: I haven't seen any private messaging here. What error did you get when you ran the code I posted?

Comment: I got this: File "project.py", line 57, in <module>
    randomlist.insert(0, header)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: Your randomlist variable is a tuple, whereas in my code it's a list. Kindly share a sample of what you get in randomlist, when you run this line `randomlist = (list(map(choice, old_list)))`